# DirectShow SDK + Adobe Flash Player PPAPI

Tags: c#, directshow, flash, ppapi

everyone.

I use this project. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437617/DirectShow-Virtual-Video-Capture-Source-Filter-in

It's work on GrabStupid.
It's work on browser (for example in Google Chrome(->GH) (in older version) it's work but doesn't work in latest version). I start to searched the problem and find it! In older version (before 45...) GH used external Adobe Flash Player(->AFP) type: NSAPI, in latest version GH using AFP type: PPAPI.
I don't know why but PPAPI don't understand my camera. I must get some specification - PPAPI understand camera (just as camera, as capture  device) but can't grab data from this device.

How know why PPAPI can't grab data from my virtual device? What difference between NSAPI and PPAPI. What I must change in my this project for PPAPI start get data?

Comment: I don't use C# but my understanding of that project is that it's a screen grabber. Are you saying it doesn't capture Flash content in the browser? You get a blank box? Did you enable / disable **hardware acceleration** in browser settings to check if maybe it works with a specific setting? Also it's possible this **"virtual and non-WDM capture"** method simply cannot grab PPAPI Plugin data so try code using actual WDM method

Comment: **You get a blank box?** - do you mean "setting box"? I have "nothing" in flash controll.
**Did you enable / disable hardware acceleration in browser settings to check** - try to switch but never happened.
**if maybe it works with a specific setting?** - what a specific setting for example? where I can try you enable it?
 **Also it's possible this "virtual and non-WDM capture" method simply cannot grab PPAPI Plugin data so try code using actual WDM method** - where I can check it and enable?

Comment: @VC.One I think I must plase the link on you ;)

Comment: I mean when you grab, do you get a blank (no image) box or are you saying it does not even begin to try?? If It tries ok but the picture is blank (all black or all white) then maybe the hardware acceleration video settings are making a problem with grabbing camera pixels. In Chrome browser you disable/enable **[like this](http://ccm.net/faq/35743-google-chrome-how-to-disable-hardware-acceleration)**, now can that grabber record Flash in browser window??

Comment: Virtual means "not-real" so if "**virtual non-WDM**" is not working maybe try code for using a real WDM capture device. Read the **[C# manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407331(v=vs.85).aspx)** for such advice or try some **[google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+record+screen+video)** for ideas. I'm not a C# expert so just something to try help yourself while you wait for an answer...

Comment: PS: I think PPAPI expects a **real** installed hardware camera. Most browsers switched to PPAPI for security reasons. So maybe fake webcams are classed as "a security issue"??... in other words not possible for a C# app to pretend it's a camera to the browser.

Comment: @VC.One First, about "security", I thinking about it, but I think if PPAPI can see my virtual camera, we can assume about right registration and right security accessing.
Second, about "blank box in Flash Player",when I select virtual cam in Flash player I don't have something! That's nothing! Not a black, not a white box, just transparent layer and that's all. I think PPAPI try to find special method for grab data but it absent.
I think I must set some attribute on old method for a grab, before compile, but I don't know, when and what?! :(